# SerialPort module in Qt creator

Tags: qt, libraries, qt6

I am creating a GUI app with Qt creator to communicate with an esp32 and control the outputs. I am currently using Qt 6.4 version, I know  lib is not available in 6.0 or 6.1 but I couldn't find anything on 6.4.

This pages advices to input QT += serial port; https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialport-index.html. In my Qt app my.pro file I declare this:

```
QT       += core gui serialport

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = serialRead
TEMPLATE = app


CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Error Message:

:-1: error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport

```
I still dont know what to do to be able to use the QSerialPort library. I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you!
```

Comment: you need to install explicitly the QT libs for that version

Answer (score 2):

Use the application QT Maintenance Tool to add serialport lib.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue with https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port

1. Install Perl (i.e Strawberry Perl)
2. Clone the qtserialport repo

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git
cd qtserialport
```

3. Checkout to suitable branch (you can list present branches with "git branch -a")

```
git checkout remotes/origin/6.3.1
```

4. Open qtserialport project with Qt Creator via CMakeLists.txt
5. In the "Projects" tab find "Build Steps" group, expand "Details" and check "install"
6. Rebuild the project from menu "Build->Rebuild"

It would be installed automatically. You may check it in the "Compile output". Note, that you have to rebuild the project for each build configuration you need.

Hope it will helps.